# How to solve the problems of lacking memory

Tags: memory-management, operating-system

Currently I'm reading books on Operating Systems Design. However, I'm not quite clear how Operating Systems do behave, when the number of free pages in memory is smaller than the working set of a process.

From the OS side, maybe it will prevent the process from being loaded into memory?

And from the developer side, what can they do to improve the situation?

Comment: Page replacement algorithms, virtual memory, MMU, etc. I think these are terms you should look up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect your confusion here is related to the meaning of the term "working set." That term has a different meaning in theoretical computer science and in operating system implementation.

In the former, a working set is the amount of memory a process requires at a given time.

In the later, a working set is the amount of physical memory a process has at a given time. (some systems may use a different definition).

A process gets what the operating system gives it. The operating system can only give what is has available. If a process needs more physical memory, the OS either gives what it has free or to takes from another process.

When a process starts up, its working set will be zero (or close to zero). A process only gets physical memory when it causes a page fault. If you monitor a program, you typically see a lot of page faults when the program starts then the number starts to level off (Unless the program uses a lot of virtual memory relative to the physical memory of the system).